# im having troubles getting my toggle script working in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

i need help 
this is the script:

```
script.Parent.Parent.Activated:connect(function()
local a = game.Workspace.LogRideToggled.Value
    if a == true then
        a = false
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    end
    if a == false then
        a = true
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    end
end)
```

this is the hirachy:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmrmG.jpg

but NOTHING happens, no errors either, except for the click sound playing
i seriously need help

Comment: The value of `a` is changed two times: `true -> false -> true` during single execution of your function.  Use `if - then - else - end` structure instead of two sequential `if`s.

Comment: although that does help, and made me go **OH**, i used an else but still dosent work, my code now: script.Parent.Parent.Activated:connect(function()
 local a = game.Workspace.LogRideToggled.Value
 if a == false then
  a = true
  script.Parent.Click:Play()
 else
  a = false
  script.Parent.Click:Play()
 end
end)

Comment: Looking at the tool, you're trying to change an object's property in the Workspace using a script. If you are using FilteringEnabled, this will not work as the Value change will not replicate. You'll have to use a RemoteEvent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is is that after you do `a == true`, you set `a` to `false`, which `a == false` then matches after.

You can solve this with an `if then else end` statement, like so:

```
script.Parent.Parent.Activated:connect(function()
    local a = game.Workspace.LogRideToggled.Value
    if a == true then
        a = false
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    else
        a = true
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    end
end)
```

However, this will only change the *local* value of `a`, which means that it will not save the change.
To fix this, we need to assign the `game.Workspace.LogRideToggled`s value of `Value` directly, which we can do like:

```
script.Parent.Parent.Activated:connect(function()
    if game.Workspace.LogRideToggled.Value == true then
        game.Workspace.LogRideToggled.Value = false
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    else
        game.Workspace.LogRideToggled.Value = true
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    end
end)
```

Although it's bad practice to repeatedly index this like this, so we can store `game.Workspace.LogRideToggled` in a local variable. You can read up on why this works but storing `value` doesn't [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

```
script.Parent.Parent.Activated:connect(function()
    local logRideToggled = game.Workspace.LogRideToggled
    if logRideToggled.Value == true then
        logRideToggled.Value = false
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    else
        logRideToggled.Value = true
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    end
end)
```

Also, the `== true` is redundant, as Lua expects a `truthy` or `falsey` value as the condition, all `== true` does in this case is give `true` or `false` if it's true of false.

```
script.Parent.Parent.Activated:connect(function()
    local logRideToggled = game.Workspace.LogRideToggled
    if logRideToggled.Value then
        logRideToggled.Value = false
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    else
        logRideToggled.Value = true
        script.Parent.Click:Play()
    end
end)
```

Yet we can clean this up a bit more, as we use `script.Parent.Click:Play()` in both cases, and we can replace `logRideToggled.Value =` with a logical not, like so.

```
script.Parent.Parent.Activated:connect(function()
    local logRideToggled = game.Workspace.LogRideToggled
    if logRideToggled.Value then
        -- Todo if truthy
    else
        -- Todo if falsey
    end
    logRideToggled.Value = not logRideToggled.Value
    script.Parent.Click:Play()
end)
```

But if you only want to toggle this value, not do anything special for either case, we can remove that entire conditional, leaving:

```
script.Parent.Parent.Activated:connect(function()
    local logRideToggled = game.Workspace.LogRideToggled
    logRideToggled.Value = not logRideToggled.Value
    script.Parent.Click:Play()
end)
```

Hope this has helped!